# Can this reduce function be written more efficiently?

Tags: javascript

I have the following input array.

```
[0: {from: "2019-05-15T15:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00", group: 0}
1: {from: "2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00", group: 0}
2: {from: "2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00", group: 0}
3: {from: "2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T17:00:00-05:00", group: 0}
4: {from: "2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00", group: 1}
5: {from: "2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00", group: 1}
6: {from: "2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T19:30:00-05:00", group: 1}]
```

And I want the output to be a collection of subarrays divided on the basis of group value. The expected output looks like below

```
[[0: {from: "2019-05-15T15:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00", group: 0}
1: {from: "2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00", group: 0}
2: {from: "2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00", group: 0}
3: {from: "2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T17:00:00-05:00", group: 0}]
,
[0: {from: "2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00", group: 1}
1: {from: "2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00", group: 1}
2: {from: "2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00", to: "2019-05-15T19:30:00-05:00", group: 1}]]
```

Below is my code to achieve the task.

```js
let rawData = '[{"from":"2019-05-15T15:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T17:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:30:00-05:00","group":1}]';
var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
var input = data.map(x => [x]);
var output = [];
output.push(input.reduce(function(acc, cur, idx, src) {
  if (acc[0].group == cur[0].group) {
    acc.push(cur[0]);
    return acc;
  } else {
    output.push(acc);
    return cur;
  }
}));
console.log(output);
```

Is there a way to write this in a more efficient way using functional concepts like map/reduce/filter/etc..??

Comment: `[0:` is not valid JavaScript. Arrays don't have property names, only objects do.

Comment: @Barmar As shown in the code, the input is converted from JSON, although his output is a JavaScript array.

Comment: What's the point of `var input = data.map(x => [x]);`

Comment: What you are looking for is partitioning by value

Comment: Not a duplicate. Slightly different use case and functionality. Plus the duplicate answer is outdated and doesn't use the `js` functional interface. I vote to reopen the question

Comment: @Barmar arrays in js DO have property names. You can check it by doing: `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(["foo", "bar"]));`, the output is `[ '0', '1', 'length' ]`. You can also double check this by doing `for(let property in array)`

Comment: @Barmar the point is to convert [object,object...] to [[obejct],[object]...] so that I can merge the internal arrays into one single thing. Again if there is a better way to do the same without all this then please let me know. TIA

Comment: @JClassic Yes, arrays are object. But array *literals* are not written that way. You can't write `array = [0: "foo", 1: "bar"]`

Comment: @Barmar true. I bet OP wrote that to make it clearer. Doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: I would like to stress on the point that I want to use functional recipes like reduce/map etc. Whoever marked it as a duplicate please note that the answers using non functional code are pretty straightforward and that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: You could try `d.reduce((prev,item) => { var id = 'g:'+item.group; !prev[id] && prev.push(prev[id] = []); prev[id].push(item); return prev; },[]).map(c => c);`

This will push an Array when new group and the final map will remove the Objects created on the first pass.

Comment: @user2703796 You don't need to convert them. You can just use `cur.group` instead of `cur[0].group`.

Comment: @Barmar I agree with the OP that that is not the right duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group` property to generate an object that holds the elements grouped by the `group value` and finally get the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
let rawData = '[{"from":"2019-05-15T15:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T17:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:30:00-05:00","group":1}]';
var data = JSON.parse(rawData);

var res = data.reduce(function(acc, cur)
{
    acc[cur.group] = acc[cur.group] || [];
    acc[cur.group].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, in the particular case that the group values goes from `[0 to N]` you can shorten the code a litle. Even more, the elements with `group` property equal to `i` will be on the index `i` of the final array:

```js
let rawData = '[{"from":"2019-05-15T15:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T15:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T16:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T17:00:00-05:00","group":0},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T18:30:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","group":1},{"from":"2019-05-15T19:00:00-05:00","to":"2019-05-15T19:30:00-05:00","group":1}]';
var data = JSON.parse(rawData);

var res = data.reduce(function(acc, cur)
{
    acc[cur.group] = acc[cur.group] || [];
    acc[cur.group].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
console.log("group 0 =>", res[0]);
console.log("group 1 =>", res[1]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use some library other than the standard Array class, you could use something like lodash.

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash'
const res = groupBy(data, 'group')
//convert to nested arrays
Object.values(res).map(e => e)
```

Below is the same as accepted answer but in ES6

```
const group = (a,c) => {
  key = c.group
  a[key] = a.hasOwnProperty(key) ? [ ...a[key], c] : [c]
  return a
}

const res = data.reduce(group, {})
```